# Finding Pythagorean Triples

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pythagorean

I've been trying to find the Pythagorean triples using Do and If statements in Mathematica.

I need to test if two integers, (a,b), construct a Pythagorean Triple where: 
1 <= a <= 100 && 1<= b <= 100

```
If[Element[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], Integers] && a < b && 
  b < Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], 
 Print["(", a, ",", b, ",", Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] ")"]]
```

The snippet gives prints the triple of they are in fact a Pythagorean triple but I am not sure on how to test for all values of a and b.
Any help would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do[ If[ IntegerQ[r = Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]], Print[{i, j, r}]], {i, 
  100}, {j, i - 1}]
```

Probably its preferable to save the results instead of using `Print`:

```
Reap[Do[ If[ IntegerQ[r = Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]], Sow[{i, j, r}]], {i, 
    100}, {j, i - 1}]][[2, 1]]
```

another way..

```
Cases[Append[#, Norm@#] & /@ 
  Subsets[Range[100], {2}], {_, _, _Integer}]
```

> {{3, 4, 5}, {5, 12, 13}, {6, 8, 10}, {7, 24, 25}, {8, 15, 17}, {9, 12,
>      15}, {9, 40, 41}, {10, 24, 26}, {11, 60, 61}, {12, 16, 20}, {12, 
>     35, 37}, {13, 84, 85}, {14, 48, 50}, {15, 20, 25}, {15, 36, 
>     39}, {16, 30, 34}, {16, 63, 65}, {18, 24, 30}, {18, 80, 82}, {20, 
>     21, 29}, {20, 48, 52}, {20, 99, 101}, {21, 28, 35}, {21, 72, 
>     75}, {24, 32, 40}, {24, 45, 51}, {24, 70, 74}, {25, 60, 65}, {27, 
>     36, 45}, {28, 45, 53}, {28, 96, 100}, {30, 40, 50}, {30, 72, 
>     78}, {32, 60, 68}, {33, 44, 55}, {33, 56, 65}, {35, 84, 91}, {36, 
>     48, 60}, {36, 77, 85}, {39, 52, 65}, {39, 80, 89}, {40, 42, 
>     58}, {40, 75, 85}, {40, 96, 104}, {42, 56, 70}, {45, 60, 75}, {48, 
>     55, 73}, {48, 64, 80}, {48, 90, 102}, {51, 68, 85}, {54, 72, 
>     90}, {56, 90, 106}, {57, 76, 95}, {60, 63, 87}, {60, 80, 100}, {60, 
>     91, 109}, {63, 84, 105}, {65, 72, 97}, {66, 88, 110}, {69, 92, 
>     115}, {72, 96, 120}, {75, 100, 125}, {80, 84, 116}}

the `Do` is actually better if you need to run to very large `n` where `Subsets` will consume a lot of memory.